# Magento2 : How Can I remove magnifier on hover and resize image of product description page?

Tags: magento2.1.5

I want to remove zoom on hover from product page and make image size bigger .

Here is my `view.xml` code

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/etc/**view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>152</width>
                <height>188</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>160</height>
            </image>
            <image id="itemgrid_category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>208</width>
                <height>260</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>270</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
                <width>265</width>
                <height>265</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>207</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>270</height>
            </image>
            <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>500</width>
                <height>500</height>
            </image>
            <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">

        <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
        <var name="gallery">

            <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
            <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
            <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
            <var name="fullscreen">
                <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
                <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
                <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
                <var name="thumbwidth">150</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
                <var name="thumbheight">150</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
                <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
                <var name="transition">
                    <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                    <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                    <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>

        <var name="magnifier">
            <var name="enabled">false</var>
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top">0</var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left">100%</var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width">300</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height">200</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>

        <var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">767px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="options">
                        <var name="navigation">dots</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
        <!-- end. Gallery and magnifier theme settings -->

        <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
        <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
        <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

        <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
        <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>           <!-- New Product image size used for zooming -->

        <var name="product_image_white_borders">0</var>
    </vars>
    <vars module="Magento_Bundle">
        <var name="product_summary_image_size">58</var>         <!-- New Product image size used for summary block-->
    </vars>
    <vars module="Js_Bundle">
        <var name="bundle_size">1MB</var>
    </vars>
    <exclude>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/captcha.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/dropdown_old.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/list.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/loader_old.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/webapi.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::moment.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/require.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::date-format-normalizer.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::legacy-build.min.js</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::modernizr</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::tiny_mce</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::varien</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/editableMultiselect</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/jstree</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/fileUploader</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::css</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::lib</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::extjs</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::prototype</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::scriptaculous</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/requirejs</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/adminhtml</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/backend</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Swagger::swagger-ui</item>
    </exclude> </view>
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: have you custom theme or you are using luma ?

Comment: @Pawan  I am using ultimo paid theme .

Comment: did you got the solution ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal  given solution not working for me .

Comment: share your view.xml code

Comment: @ManojDeswal shared

Comment: I ll check in a hour and will revert you back

Comment: @ManojDeswal sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67166/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-learner).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your XML code with little correction , this line was entered twice

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
```

Once false and once true , see edit code below

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>152</width>
                <height>188</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>160</height>
            </image>
            <image id="itemgrid_category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>208</width>
                <height>260</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
            <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>270</height>
            </image>
            <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>78</width>
                <height>78</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
                <width>265</width>
                <height>265</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image"> <!-- change this for main image size -->
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">   <!-- change this for main image size -->
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image"> <!-- change this for main image size -->
                <width>700</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
                <width>90</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>207</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
                <width>270</width>
                <height>270</height>
            </image>
            <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>500</width>
                <height>500</height>
            </image>
            <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
                <width>285</width>
                <height>285</height>
            </image>
            <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>75</height>
            </image>
            <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
                <width>135</width>
                <height>135</height>
            </image>
            <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
                <width>75</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>113</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image>
            <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">

        <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
        <var name="gallery">

            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
            <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
            <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
            <var name="fullscreen">
                <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
                <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
                <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
                <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
                <var name="thumbwidth">150</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
                <var name="thumbheight">150</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
                <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
                <var name="transition">
                    <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                    <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                    <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>

        <var name="magnifier">
            <var name="enabled">false</var>
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top">0</var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left">100%</var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width">300</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height">200</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>

        <var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">767px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="options">
                        <var name="navigation">dots</var>
                    </var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
        <!-- end. Gallery and magnifier theme settings -->

        <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
        <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
        <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

        <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
        <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>           <!-- New Product image size used for zooming -->

        <var name="product_image_white_borders">0</var>
    </vars>
    <vars module="Magento_Bundle">
        <var name="product_summary_image_size">58</var>         <!-- New Product image size used for summary block-->
    </vars>
    <vars module="Js_Bundle">
        <var name="bundle_size">1MB</var>
    </vars>
    <exclude>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/captcha.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/dropdown_old.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/list.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/loader_old.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::mage/webapi.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::moment.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/require.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::date-format-normalizer.js</item>
        <item type="file">Lib::legacy-build.min.js</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::modernizr</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::tiny_mce</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::varien</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/editableMultiselect</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/jstree</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/fileUploader</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::css</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::lib</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::extjs</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::prototype</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::scriptaculous</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/requirejs</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/adminhtml</item>
        <item type="directory">Lib::mage/backend</item>
        <item type="directory">Magento_Swagger::swagger-ui</item>
    </exclude> </view>
```

To change main image size I have put  comment in front of respective code in your file. like below . Currently its 700*700.. you can change it as required.

```
<image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image"> <!-- change this for main image size -->
      <width>700</width>
      <height>700</height>
</image>
```

Also need to adjust size of these container to see bigger size image

```
product-info-main

product media
```

After that run following commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I hope this will help you out

Comment: I got alternative method aswell , In ultimo theme backend there is option to off megnifer .

Comment: cheers ! you are going good

Comment: There ? I need a small help bro

Comment: Yes ! you there ?

Comment: yes have idea about this ?  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197873/change-resolution-of-magento-2-theme

Comment: No question found on above link

Answer (score 5):

You have to disable **magnifier** and **full screen** in your theme.
change `etc/view.xml` file of your theme as below

```
<var name="gallery">
    <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
    ...
</var>

<var name="magnifier">
   <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

You can also change the image size for product page from this file.

Comment: Where I can resize that main image ?

Comment: search for `<image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">` in **etc/view.xml** file.